# Angularjs - Making a button behave like a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Im trying to make ngstyle give an interface a list view for the users easily and have encountered an issue someone may be able to assist with.

I am trying to use ngstyle and ngmodel to both alter the style and hide icons when a button is clicked, ideally I would like a button that allow you to switch between list and tile view modes.

Here is the checkbox system as it stands (which is clunky and not user friendly, but works).

```html
    <p style="color:black; font-size:14px; margin-left:50px;" class="label">List View
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="visible" aria-label="Toggle ngShow" style="margin-left:5px;" ng-click="myStyle={width:'100%', height:'30px', 'text-align':'left', top:'7px', 'font-size':'14px'}">
    </p>
    <p style="color:black; font-size:14px;" class="label">Tile View
      <input type="button" ng-model="unchecked" aria-label="Toggle ngShow" style="margin-left:5px;" ng-click="myStyle={}">
    </p>
```

And here is what ive done to the icons so they hide when checked:

```css
  .hideItem {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
```

```html
<i ng-class="{'hideItem': visible}" class="icon fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>
```

What I need is for preferably a single button that is "Change View" which accomplishes the same task Im achieving here but easier.

Any assistance or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Mant thanks in advance

Comment: Basically I need the following code to be within one button that toggles between list and tile view, when i click the toggle it both hides the icons and then re-styles the page. Then when i click again it resets the style and shows the icons again.

Here are the 3 functions broken up:

Comment: 'code'           p.label(style="color:black; font-size:14px; margin-left:10px;") Hide Icons
            input(type='checkbox', ng-model='visible', aria-label='Hide icons', style="margin-left:5px;")
          .btn.btn-default.pull-right(aria-label='List view button', style="margin-left:5px;", ng-click="myStyle={width:'100%', height:'30px', 'text-align':'left', top:'7px', 'font-size':'14px'}" ng-model="listView") List View
          .btn.btn-default.pull-right(aria-label='Tile view button', style="margin-left:5px;", ng-click="myStyle={}") Tile View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using ng-class as below:

```html
<ul uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="simple-btn-keyboard-nav" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li role="menuitem"><a ng-click="tog=1" style="text-transform: initial;" uib-tooltip="New List View" ng-model="tileView">List View</a>
        <!--a(ng-click="myStyle={width:'100%', height:'30px', 'text-align':'left', top:'5px', 'font-size':'14px', 'margin-left':'5px',}" style="text-transform: initial;", uib-tooltip="New List View", ng-model="listView") List View-->
      </li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a ng-click="tog=2" style="text-transform: initial;" uib-tooltip="Original Tiled View" ng-model="tileView">Tile View</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And bound it using the following:

```html
<a uib-tooltip="{{item.Title}}" ng-repeat="item in linkList = (WorkspaceCtrl.workspaceLinkStore.list | filter:{Active:true} | limitTo:WorkspaceCtrl.itemsPerCategory)" ng-href="{{item.Url}}" target="_blank" ng-class="{items:tog==1}" class="item">
<p class="title">{{item.Title}}</p></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use ng-show directly as it is a directive built into Angular to toggle state between two buttons - the tile view button and the list view button. The one that is displayed can be toggled by an expression

```
<button type="button" ng-model="unchecked" ng-show="expression" ng-click="changeView()">List View</button>
<button type="button" ng-model="unchecked" ng-show="expression" ng-click="changeView()">Title View</button>
```

The expression in ng-show if truthy will display the button and if falsy will hide the button. You can use the same expression in each of these button tags and just invert the expression using !

In the Javascript, you would toggle the expression to/from truthy with changeView()

Here is a link to the documentation on ng-show:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow

Comment: That looks good, however I am already using the ngclick function to style the page into list mode.